# Elastic search and Codeigniter (PHP)

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-get-contents, elasticsearch

I'm trying using ElasticSearch with Codeigniter framework.

What i did is just install ElasticSearch and copyed ( :P ) a good PHP library found on the web to CI libraries:

```
    class Elasticsearch {

  public $config_file = 'elasticsearch';
  public $index;

  function __construct($index = false){
      $CI =& get_instance();
      $CI->config->load($this->config_file);
      $this->server = $CI->config->item('es_server');

  }

  function call($path, $http = array()){
    if (!$this->index) throw new Exception('$this->index needs a value');
    return json_decode(file_get_contents($this->server . '/' . $this->index . '/' . $path, NULL, stream_context_create(array('http' => $http))));
  }

  //curl -X PUT http://localhost:9200/{INDEX}/
  function create(){
     $this->call(NULL, array('method' => 'PUT'));
  }

  //curl -X DELETE http://localhost:9200/{INDEX}/
  function drop(){
     $this->call(NULL, array('method' => 'DELETE'));
  }

  //curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/{INDEX}/_status
  function status(){
    return $this->call('_status');
  }

  //curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/{INDEX}/{TYPE}/_count -d {matchAll:{}}
  function count($type){
    return $this->call($type . '/_count', array('method' => 'GET', 'content' => '{ matchAll:{} }'));
  }

  //curl -X PUT http://localhost:9200/{INDEX}/{TYPE}/_mapping -d ...
  function map($type, $data){
    return $this->call($type . '/_mapping', array('method' => 'PUT', 'content' => $data));
  }

  //curl -X PUT http://localhost:9200/{INDEX}/{TYPE}/{ID} -d ...
  function add($type, $id, $data){
   echo  $this->call($type . '/' . $id, array('method' => 'PUT', 'content' => $data));
  }

  //curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/{INDEX}/{TYPE}/_search?q= ...
  function query($type, $q){
    return $this->call($type . '/_search?' . http_build_query(array('q' => $q)));
  }
}
```

then i'm trying creating indexes and simply retrieve them:

```
$this->load->library('elasticsearch');
                 $this->elasticsearch->index = 'comments';
                 $this->elasticsearch->create();
                 $data = '{author:jhon,datetime:2001-09-09 00:02:04}';
                 $this->elasticsearch->add($type ='details',$id = '1',$data);
```

when i run this code it show me errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: file_get_contents(http://localhost:9200/comments/) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

Filename: libraries/Elasticsearch.php

Line Number: 19
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Content-type not specified assuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Filename: libraries/Elasticsearch.php

Line Number: 19
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: file_get_contents(http://localhost:9200/comments/details/1) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

Filename: libraries/Elasticsearch.php

Line Number: 19
```

does i'm mistaking/missed somenthing? sorry but i'm newbie about elasticsearch and also a little bit with php :P

cause if i go to:

```
http://localhost:9200/comments/details/1

//it prints in window
 {"_index":"comments","_type":"details","_id":"1","exists":false}
```

Comment: i want to ask from how to use Elastic Search with CodeIgniter. and also how to install in codeIgniter..

Comment: @PuzzledBoy CI installation link : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/       then u can use libraries like this https://github.com/confact/elasticsearch-codeigniter-library/blob/master/application/libraries/elasticsearch.php to interface your CI with elastic search

Comment: ok thankx.. it could helpful for me.

Comment: Can we chat for a couple of minutes.. if you have time.. i need to ask about elasticsearch basic. :)

Comment: @PuzzledBoy i am not sure i can help you cause its long time i dont use elasticsearch i probably forgot how to use it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, but my guess would be your call to `add()`:

```
$this->elasticsearch->add($type ='details',$id = '1',$data);
```

You don't want to be setting values here. I would assume you'd get a php error before an HTTP bad request, but I would try this first:

```
$this->elasticsearch->add('details','1',$data);
```

Your `add()` method already knows what the arguments represent, so you just need to pass the details.

**Also**

It looks like your json might be malformed.

```
// change
$data = '{author:jhon,datetime:2001-09-09 00:02:04}';

// to
$data = '{author:"jhon",datetime:2001-09-09 00:02:04}';
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions yep i missed up some basics on my sintax , but the error persist, i think there is somenthing i'm missed that is much more important, uhm ...

Comment: @sbaaaang did you find the solution. i am not able to insert data

Comment: @dhpratik nope , i have to admit i gave up at that time, i've never used elasticsearch then, cause of too much troubles with CI :P for the next PHP project i will move to Laravel seems much more better at the moment for me

Comment: @dhpratik do you get any error? can you show something i may help i guess

Comment: it did not give any error.but when trying to add data to an index, it did not get inserted. later i changed the library function of 'add'. the add function was using `http put`, i changed it to `post`

Answer (score 3):

An old question, but deserves an update.
Use this [plugin](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php).

Put your `composer.json` file in the application folder:

```
{
     "require": {
     "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~2.0"
     }
}
```

To install [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) and elasticsearch plugin execute these commands in bash shell:

```
curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar install --no-dev
```

Install `php-curl` and restart apache server:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Create a `Elasticsearch.php` file in the libraries folder (codeigniter), and put this code inside:

```
<?php 
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

class Elasticsearch{

    public $client;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
    } 
}
```

You can autoload elasticsearch by editing autoload.php in config folder:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array(/*[some other library,]*/'elasticsearch');
```

Then in your model/controller use:

```
$this->elasticsearch->client->index($params);
```

Answer (score 2):

The PHP library that you have given is not defining content-type, that's why you are getting the message: "Content-type not specified".

Check the PHP library here and also go through the README.txt. It has detailed notes which will be useful to beginners and you may want to go through them:
https://github.com/niranjan-uma-shankar/Elasticsearch-PHP-class

If you use this library, then you can initialize the class like this:

```
$this->load->library('elasticsearch');
$elasticSearch = new $this->elasticsearch;
$elasticsearch->index = 'comments';
$elasticsearch->type = 'details';
$elasticsearch->create();
$data = '{"author" : "jhon", "datetime" : "2001-09-09 00:02:04"}';
$elasticsearch->add(1, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the functions passing the parameters without quotes (single or double):

```
$this->elasticsearch->add(details, 1, $data);
```

In addition, for me it's easier to work with arrays and then encode it into json objects:

```
$data = array('author' => 'john', 'datetime' => '2001-09-09 00:02:04');
$this->elasticsearch->add(details, 1, json_encode($data));
```