# How to convert this given tutorial video(php core) into codeigniter(elasticsearch:9200)

Tags: php, codeigniter, elasticsearch

I am newbie for codeigniter and get a chance to learn alot from it. Now i just wanted to include the **elasticsearch** in **Codeigniter** and searched for tutorial vedios there is nothing i can find and last i followed this tutorial so that i can make some changes and include in codeigniter . but i struck . Anyhelp will be great. Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
 require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
 $es= new Elasticsearch\Client([ 'hosts' => ['127.0.0.1:9200'] ]);
```

I just wanted to get this code into codeigniter . it is init.php file inside the App folder when you follow the tutorial. It is like there is no much tutorials to include elasticsearch and codeigniter.

I have followed following tutorials

Ref : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xb1dHLg-Lk

[image]

After trying this github demo. which given below.I have included all the files needed and tried to add the index then i got this error.

```
$insert_data = array('carrier' => $this->input->post('carrier'),
                'shipping_type' => $this->input->post('shipping_type'),
                'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
                'restrictions' => $this->input->post('restrictions'),
                'vendor_id' => $vendor_id,
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s'),
                'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s'),
            );
            if ($insert_data != null) {
                $insert_data = $this->Shipping_options_model->insert($insert_data);
                var_dump($this->elasticsearch->add("people", $insert_data, $insert_data));
                exit;
```

Comment: .please add code so that someone can findout where you are doing wrong.Thanks

Comment: thank you <?php 

require_once  'vendor/autoload.php';

$es= new Elasticsearch\Client([
 'hosts' => ['127.0.0.1:9200']
 ]);  I just wanted to get this code into codeigniter . it is init.php file inside the App folder when you follow the tutorial. It is like there is no much tutorials to include elasticsearch and codeigniter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097238/elastic-search-and-codeigniter-php or you can use https://github.com/confact/elasticsearch-codeigniter-library

Comment: Thank you. i will try that all and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you for helping it out @iCoders

Comment: really sry i'll follow up from next time. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To use GD Library you have to enable gd library in your php.ini file

```
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

and restart server

Example

```
<?php
/**
 * PHP GD
 * create a simple image with GD library
 * 
 */
//setting the image header in order to proper display the image
header("Content-Type: image/png");
//try to create an image
$im = @imagecreate(800, 600)
    or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
//set the background color of the image
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xDD);
//set the color for the text
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 133, 14, 91);
//adf the string to the image
imagestring($im, 5, 300, 300,  "I'm a pretty picture:))", $text_color);
//outputs the image as png
imagepng($im);
//frees any memory associated with the image 
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Ref:

http://code.runnable.com/UnF1kdvayk91AADH/how-to-create-a-simple-image-with-gd-library-for-php